# How Do I manually remove malformed Packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I tried to install typo3 via the apt-get package manager on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy. During the installation the Package typo3-dummy could not be configured and remained in status: half-installed

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all typo3-dummy 
(Reading database ... 107326
files and directories currently installed.) Removing typo3-dummy ...
apache2-maintscript-helper invoked from a modified environment. Please
hint required arguments manually dpkg: error processing typo3-dummy
(--purge):  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error
exit status 1 Processing triggers for ureadahead ... Errors were
encountered while processing:  typo3-dummy
```

What else could I try to get rid of this package? I'd like to avoid fresh installation.
Ty

**EDIT**: using sudo apt-get install -f returns the following output

```
ben@cloudy:/etc$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  typo3-dummy
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 484 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 107326 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing typo3-dummy ...
apache2-maintscript-helper invoked from a modified environment. Please hint requ          ired arguments manually
dpkg: error processing typo3-dummy (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encoun          tered while processing:
 typo3-dummy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: why manually you want to remove it >

Comment: because all the "classic" ways seem to fail ... purge / remove nothing works

Comment: update my answer

Comment: your answer worked like a charm! Thank you very much

Comment: welcome my friend , any time

Comment: Had the same problem and fixed it like nux said. Thanks a lot for that!
But I'd take **gedit** to edit */var/lib/dpkg/status*: sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status For those who are not familiar with the console ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try :

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

remove all entries about the package and save , then try again.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: i tried it and posted the output above.

Comment: Yes, I'd have used gedit or at least nano as an editor instead of vi, in case some newbie stumbles upon this, but your answer is very good. Concise and efficient. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I mistakenly loaded mssql-server instead of the PDO for php, this is the answer that worked after 2 hours of searching! Thak you

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, create fake file:

```
touch ~/Desktop/test.sh
```

Step 2, create symlink:

```
sudo ln -fs  ~/Desktop/test.sh /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks
```

Step3, run autoremove:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please explain in a little more details what this approach does and how it solves the issues asked in the question?