# dpkg: error processing package gosa

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. After upgrade I have tried `sudo apt-get update` in 16.04 and I got the following error.

```
dpkg: error processing package 
   gosa 
(--remove):  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:
  gosa 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `apt-get update / upgrade` is two separate commands... or are you saying `apt get update` or `apt get upgrade` fails with dpkg error?

Comment: Are you using `sudo` with these commands?

Comment: Yes I am using sudo with this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include **exactly** what commands you are using, in what context, and what errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned in the following post has resolved the issue

[How Do I manually remove malformed Packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430252/how-do-i-manually-remove-malformed-packages)