# Trying to install php7

Tags: software-installation, apache2, dpkg

Trying to do a lamp install I get this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: please add more information as per how you went about, cause as I see it from your command it says to me _I have installed php7, and when trying to install "libapache2-mod-php7.0 module" I get an error_... SO it's either you are trying to install the _module_ first before _php7_ or you have and are getting errors with installing the module in question

Comment: There is "1 not fully installed or removed." So, try with `sudo apt install -f` to *fix broken*, after that `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, and then try again `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`.

Comment: Full command was as follows: $ sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-cgi php7.0-gd

Comment: sudo apt install -f

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Have you tried wit something like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/430254/566421)?

Comment: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade gives same error emssage as sudo apt install -f

Comment: Also you can to purge this package ant try to install it again: `sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.0`.

Comment: Spas: apt purge and install did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889401/trying-to-install-php7/986710#comment1390546_889401)

```
sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

worked for me too.